# post-up default gateway does not get picked up

Tags: networking, interface

I have a Proxmox 5 host with some Ubuntu 14 and 16 VMs. My problem now is, that my default gateway on the guests gets not correctly set after a reboot.

Here is the config:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto ens18
iface ens18 inet static
        address 172.16.1.90
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 172.16.1.1

auto ens19
iface ens19 inet static
        address 94.130.242.98
        netmask 255.255.255.255
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
        post-up ip route add 176.9.11.218 dev ens19
        post-up ip route add default via 176.9.11.218 dev ens19
        pre-down ip route del default via 176.9.11.218 dev ens19
        pre-down ip route del 176.9.11.218 dev ens19

iface ens19 inet6 static
        address 2a01:4f8:141:54d8::5
        netmask 64
        gateway 2a01:4f8:141:54d8::2
```

This are the routes after rebooting.

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.16.1.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens18
172.16.1.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens18
176.9.11.218    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ens19
```

Can someone give me a clue on how to solve this.

Greetings